# postgreSQL There is an entry for table "xxx", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: postgresql, postgis

What is the proper way to write this query in `postgreSQL`?
I am trying to normalize (i.e. standardize) an address. I can use `pagc` with no problem if I feed it a hardcoded address. However, I need to feed it an address parsed from parts. I see there are several similar questions here on stack overflow referencing the same error. These queries are complex and are all pretty different from mine, so I couldn't get to the solution from reading the other posts.

I have tried:

```
with full_address as (home_address1 || ','|| home_city ||','|| home_state ||,','|| home_zip) update contacts set (home_house_num, home_predirection, home_street_name, home_street_type,home_postdirection, home_unit_num) = (addy.address_alphanumeric,addy.predirabbrev,addy.streetname, addy.streettypeabbrev,addy.postdirabbrev,addy.internal) FROM pagc_normalize_address(full_address) AS addy where contact_id = 833826;
```

This throws error:

> syntax error at or near "home_address1"
>   LINE 26:     with full_address as (home_address1 || ','|| home_city |.

I have also tried:

```
update contacts set (home_house_num, home_predirection, home_street_name, home_street_type,home_postdirection, home_unit_num) = (addy.address_alphanumeric,addy.predirabbrev,addy.streetname, addy.streettypeabbrev,addy.postdirabbrev,addy.internal) FROM pagc_normalize_address(home_address1 ||','||home_city||','||home_state||','||','||home_zip) AS addy where contact_id = 833826;
```

Error:

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "contacts"
>       LINE 24: ...abbrev,addy.internal) FROM pagc_normalize_address(home_addre...
>                                                                     ^
>       HINT:  There is an entry for table "contacts", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
>       SQL state: 42P10
>       Character: 2297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is gibberish, the second makes sense but fails because you cannot use a lateral reference to the updated table's columns in the `FROM` clause.

Try a CTE like this:

```
WITH addy AS (
   SELECT addy.* FROM
      contacts
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      pagc_normalize_address(home_address1 
 || ',' || home_city || ',' || home_state || ',' || ',' || home_zip) AS addy
   WHERE contacts.contact_id = 833826
)
UPDATE contacts
SET (home_house_num, home_predirection, home_street_name, home_street_type,home_postdirection, home_unit_num)
    = (addy.address_alphanumeric,addy.predirabbrev,addy.streetname, addy.streettypeabbrev,addy.postdirabbrev,addy.internal)
FROM addy
WHERE contact_id = 833826;
```